# ntheorem: Set normalfont to Theorem-Note

Tags: theorems, ntheorem

What is the key to set normalfont to the theorem-note and its brackets and its punct?

[image]

```
\documentclass{scrreprt} 
\usepackage{ntheorem}
\theoremseparator{.} 
\theorembodyfont{\upshape}
%\theoremheaderfont{\normalfont}
\newtheorem{defi}{Definition}

\begin{document}
\begin{defi}[Normalfont Here]
Blablabla
\end{defi}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You didn't indicate which of `ntheorem`'s pre-defined theorem styles you employ -- `plain`, `break`, `change`, `break`, `margin`, `marginbreak`, `nonumberplain`, `nonumberbreak`, `empty`, and `emptybreak` -- so I'll assume you're fine with using the default style, *viz.*, `plain`.

If this assumption is appropriate, just add the following instructions to the preamble (*after* loading `ntheorem`, obviously):

```
\makeatletter
\renewtheoremstyle{plain}%
  {\item[\hskip\labelsep \theorem@headerfont ##1\ ##2\theorem@separator]}%
  {\item[\hskip\labelsep \theorem@headerfont ##1\ ##2 \mdseries (##3)\theorem@separator]}
\makeatother
```

Just in case you're curious, the default for the fourth line in the preceding chunk is

```
  {\item[\hskip\labelsep \theorem@headerfont ##1\ ##2\ (##3)\theorem@separator]}
```

Thus, the only change consists of the insertion of `\mdseries` immediately before `(##3)`.

Comment: Oha, I understand.